# SAGE hangs inside emacs

Tags: python, emacs, sage

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and emacs 24.3. I have successfully downloaded sage, and sage_mode. My problem is that when I try to run SAGE in emacs it doesn't load.

When I try to run SAGE with `M-x sage` it will then say: `Run sage (like this): /home/path/to/sage`. I hit enter then everything freezes inside of emacs with a message in the mini-buffer:  `Sent python-eldoc-setup-code` Emacs stays frozen until I quit with `C-g` After that SAGE appears normally. If I run sage in the terminal everything starts up quickly and normally as I would expect.

Here is the output from my messages buffer:

```
Sent python-shell-completion-setup-code
Sent python-ffap-setup-code
Sent python-eldoc-setup-code
```

1. Why is it freezing like this and not starting normally?

I have seen a few bug reports that look similar, which are specifically problems with the python shell (SAGE runs on top of python).

Here is one [bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.bug/JWvREtalP98) report.

**EDIT:** I am looking for specific instructions on how to fix the sage process that runs through emacs. Type `M-x emacs-version` I know that I have Emacs 24.3.1. Please let me know if you need any more information to help me fix my issue.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry you're experiencing this.

This sounds like a bug (in sage-mode) that I fixed a while ago in which it would get stuck waiting for the prompt.  What version of `sage-mode` are you using?  `C-h v sage-mode-version RET`.  The latest released version is `0.10` and doesn't have such a bug to the best of my knowledge.  If you are using an older version please upgrade.  Otherwise I would really appreciate a bug report at https://bitbucket.org/gvol/sage-mode/issues?status=new&status=open so that I don't forget it.

Also, what version of Sage are you using, and do you have anything in your `~/.sage/init.sage`?

Comment: There is no file in `~/.sage/init.sage` I am using version `sage-mode` version .8, how do I upgrade? I am also using sage 5.12

Comment: I just updated to 0.9.1 using sage -f sage_mode in the terminal, but emacs is still using version 0.8... How do I change that?

Comment: You can simply delete all the old `.el` and `.elc` files.  I don't remember off the top of my head where they are located in Sage 5.12, but when you install sage_mode again it will tell you (and in fact, I think it should delete them automatically).  Make sure to update your .emacs to point to the correct place and restart Emacs.  If you have any further problems let me know.

Comment: I have sage mode 0.10 and I still has this problem.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious, please update your version of sage mode.  0.10 is quite old in terms of bug fixes.  You can do `sage -f https://bitbucket.org/gvol/sage-mode/downloads/sage_mode-0.13.spkg`.  If you still have a problem, please open a bug.

Comment: Just as a comment: I still had this bug with sage_mode 0.12. Just upgraded to 0.13 and it works now. However, the buffer does open up with at least 5 blank sage: prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config WRT to commands prefixes.

"python-" expects python.el

"py-" expects python-mode.el

`(load "python")` loads mode from python.el

It provides 'python

`(load "python-mode")` loads mode from python-mode.el

It provides 'python-mode

BTW the bug linked to doesn't exist in python-mode.el

Comment: AFAIK this bug was never in a released version of Emacs (it was fixed before the 24.3 release), so it shouldn't affect him.

Comment: @Andreas I don't know what WRT is, and I don't understand your point. It seems like you have listed a set of random facts about python modes for me. What am I missing?

Comment: @Stefan I use Ubuntu, and after an `apt-get` package update/upgrade, `apt-get` still tells me that I have the latest version of emacs.

Comment: WRT is "with respect to", I think.